# Cypress: How to retrieve One-time Passcode from created virtual device on Mailosaur

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-custom-commands, cypress-mailosaur

I have a virtual device set up on Mailosaur, as seen below.
[image: Mailosaur Virtual Device]

Within this image, you can see the "Reveal One-Time Passcode" button.

I have checked that the passcode works with the website I am working with, and now I am trying to create a Cypress test to retrieve this passcode, and type it into a text field.

The code I currently have in the Cypress.feature file looks like this.
[image: CypressExample.feature]

The code I currently have in the Cypress.js file looks like this.
[image: CypressExample.js]

I am unsure if the "mailosaurGetDeviceOtp" function does what I am trying to do. Note that 'deviceName' is the same name that is in the first image, mailosaurINT.

How do I get the one time passcode from the virtual device on Mailosaur, and then type it into a text box to be used?

Answer (score 2):

There's a test in `cypress-mailosaur` that illustrates how to use the custom command,

[Ref](https://github.com/mailosaur/cypress-mailosaur/blob/6d5445bcd6dc79f29a1429350673c67ae1dfa583/test/react-app/cypress/e2e/devices.cy.js#L20)

```js
it('.mailosaurGetDeviceOtp should retrieve an otp via device ID', (done) => {
  cy.mailosaurGetDeviceOtp(createdDevice.id).then((otpResult) => {
    expect(otpResult.code).to.be.a('string');
    expect(otpResult.code).to.have.lengthOf(6);
    done();
  });
});
```

so your test would be this (I don't think the `done()` call is needed here)

```js
cy.mailosaurGetDeviceOtp(Cypress.env('deviceName')).then((otpResult) => {
  cy.get(`input[placeholder="${placeholderText}"]`)
    .type(otpResult)
});
```